# Embed user entered phone number to url

Tags: html, forms, phone-number

I am new to this forum and I am almost complete novice with HTML coding

My requirement is as below.

I just found out that my VOIP provider has a feature called Dial By URL and it works as it sounds
Sample URL 
https://soho66.co.uk/url_dial.aspx?f=1000027806&h=87EF4366186C4E4A5F4A705&t=0123456789

I would like to use this feature in my joomla website by asking the user to input their phone number, recaptcha verification and press Call Now button to establish the connection.

As you can see in the above link the last 10 digits are the phone numbers.

Can anyone help me to achieve this please?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: So, what is it exactly you want help with? Creating the input? Recaptcha? Creating the url with the phone number? You need to be a bit more specific =)

Comment: Hello Mario, thanks for your response. I need to create a form with input field for visitor's to enter their contact number and a recaptcha verification and Call Now button. When Call Now button is clicked the URL should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. You really need to do some research into joomla components to get you started.

Have a look here http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_component_-_Part_1 or google search 'joomla component'